# solr search - Result missing if I miss a word located between two words

Tags: java, search, solr, tokenize, stop-words

I have a problem while searching with Solr.
I indexed some data, then I try to search for a document.
In this document I have fields named: **coord_address** with the value **"48 rue de la Frémondière"**
If I search **searchword: "48 rue de la Fremondiere"**, I have a result, **searchword: "48 rue de la"** or **"La Fremondiere"** I also have the good result.

If I miss a word located between two words (**48 rue de Fremondiere**) by removing the (**le**) or (**48 rue la Fremondiere**) removing the (**de**) I have no result.

Someone can help me.

here is my schema.xml

```
<field name="coord_adress" type="text"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false" />


<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false">
   <analyzer type="index">
        <!-- Remplace les apostrophes par des espaces pour le tokenizer -->
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-wordSeparators.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"  preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
        <!-- Remplace les apostrophes par des espaces pour le tokenizer -->
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-wordSeparators.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"  preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

what I do not understand, in the interface the analysis, I have terms that match but my query does not return result

[See the screenshot of the analysis here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhMX9.png)

Comment: which query you're using? just term query or something more complex?

Comment: I am using the solr web interface for the query. My request is: **http: // localhost: 8983 / solr / adel_online / select? Indent = on & q = coord_adress: "48 rue de la Fremondiere" & wt = json** this request returns a good result and **http: // localhost: 8983 / solr / adel_online / select? Indent = on & q = coord_address: "48 rue la Fremondiere" & wt = json** does not return any results because i am removed the (de)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using double quotes, which means you're searching for an exact match phrase.

Remove the quotes and the search should work in both cases.

It's always recommended to use the Solr analysis tool when you need to understand the behavior of some indexed and queried input: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/analysis-screen.html

Comment: If I remove the quotes, I have this result:
 **{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "coord_adresse2: 48 rue de la Frémondière",
      "indent": "on",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1508934662307"}},
  "Error":{
    "metadata": [
      "error-class", "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class", "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg": "undefined field _text_",
    "code": 400}}**

Comment: You've changed the field in your query to coord_adresse2. Try with the original coord_adress and please provide the request url if it doesn't work.

Comment: excuse me I was wrong on the name of the field. The name of the field **coord_adress** and the request url that does not provide any results are: **http: // localhost: 8983 / solr / adel_online / select? Indent = on & q = coord_adress: 48 rue la Fremondiere & wt = json**. The field in solr contains **"coord_adress": "48 rue de la Fremondiere"**

Comment: Try using the solr analysis tab in your solr admin page to understand what's going on with your indexed and queried input: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/analysis-screen.html

Comment: This is because the default search field if a field isn't provided in the query is `_text_`. Since you're only prefixing the first term (48) with a field name, the rest of the terms are attempted matched against the default field, which doesn't exist. Use the edismax query handler ( `&defType=edismax`), `coord_adress` as the query field (`&qf=coord_adress`) and the plain query as your query (`q=48 rue de la Frémondière`). That error is not related to the analysis chain.

Comment: If I put the &qf = coord_adress, I have a result but not what I want. This does a search that is far too global and suddenly I have documents that have no correspondence with my search terms. My problem: if **searchTerm="48 rue de la Fremondiere"** I have a result, and if **searchTerm = "48 rue Fremondiere"** I have no result.

Comment: This is where you bring in the analysis part - that will tell you exactly why something matches and something doesn't match. The ngramfilter you have will cause _a lot_ of matches at the beginning of words, while throwing away short terms. Also, you're using both a tokenizer and the word delimiter filter on index, but not on query - the analysis page will tell you exactly why a query doesn't match your indexed value.